# JS - jQuery Remove all bands that contains a class but keep the one with the ID that is in the URL

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need your help. I am new to Javascript and jQuery. I have something to do.
I have a list of divs with the same class but each div has a specific ID.
Let say I have this:

```
<div class="list" id="apples"></div>
<div class="list" id="bananas"></div>
<div class="list" id="pineapples"></div>
```

I have the URL https://johndoe.com/apples, https://johndoe.com/bananas and https://johndoe.com/pineapples.

All divs are displayed on the 3 pages but I want to have only the div with id apples displayed on the Apples page and the others to be entirely removed not hidden. I want the same for each page (bananas displayed on bananas' page...). So what I wrote is this. I thought that changing apples div's class to something else would avoid it to be deleted.

```
var fruitId = val['id'];
function displayDiv()
{
    var selectedSection = document.getElementById(fruitId);
    if (window.location.href.indexOf(fruitId) > 0) 
    {
        selectedSection.setAttribute('class', 'selectedfruit');
        $("div.list").remove();
    }
}
```

Do not pay attention to fruitId it's 'apples', 'bananas' and 'pineapples' in the JSON file and I have the correct list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`filter(function)`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function) and check the id in the function

```
$("div.list").filter(function(){
   return !window.location.href.includes(this.id)
}).remove();
```

This will remove only the ones where the id value is not in the href

Comment: Thanks for your help. I got this error message: Uncaught TypeError: window.location.href.contains is not a function

Also it's returning only the 1st one so I have apples div on all pages (bananas and pineapples page).

Comment: Ahh my bad. It should be [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) not contains()

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works perfectly BUT I still have Uncaught TypeError: window.location.href.contains is not a function

```
$("div.list").filter(function(){
   if (window.location.href.indexOf(this.id) > -1)
    {
        return !window.location.href.contains(this.id)
    }
    $("div.list").remove();
});
```

What can I do to remove the error? If I replace the "contains" with "indexOf" then I don't have any results.